# ¿Como obtener la fecha actual a través del DatePickerDialog?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Tengo un DatePicker que se muestra en un EditText. El problema que tengo es que no me muestra la fecha actual. Como logro que me de los valores de la fecha actual?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
public class Recuerdame extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

Button botonfecha;
EditText editfecha;
private  int dia, mes, año;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recuerdame);     
    botonfecha =(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonfecha);
    editfecha =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editfecha);
    botonfecha.setOnClickListener(this);
 }

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v==botonfecha){
        final Calendar calendario = Calendar.getInstance();
        dia=calendario.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        mes=calendario.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        año=calendario.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                editfecha.setText(dayOfMonth+"/"+(monthOfYear+1)+"/"+year);
            }
        }
        ,dia, mes, año);
        datePickerDialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: Calendar.getInstance() Debería devolverte la fecha y hora actual. Estás utilizando un emulador ? seguro que tiene bien configuradas la fecha y la hora?

Comment: No utilizo un emulador, utilizo un celular.

Comment: Hola el problema que tuve fue el mismo, no capturaba la fecha siempre aparecía una fecha muy antigua, la solución fue que había puesto al revés los parámetros, es decir primero colocamos: el año, luego el mes, luego el día. Según veo tú estas colocando día, mes y año, no pierdes nada con probar, a mi me funcionó. Saludos!!!

Answer (score 2):

El [**DatePickerDialog**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.html) (al igual que el [TimePickerDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TimePickerDialog.html)) toma la fecha  actual del sistema operativo, si no tienes sincronizada correctamente la fecha, esta se mostraría incorrecta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si estas usando un emulador, asegura que tu pc tenga la fecha y hora actual correcta.

Puedes ir a los settings y configurar que la hora y fecha sean provistas por la red, lo que es comúnmente correcto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

en onCreate agrega`setFechaActual();` y luego creas el método:

```
public void setFechaActual()
{
    editfecha = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editfecha);
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    año = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mes = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    dia = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    String s = formatter.format(c.getTime());
    editfecha.setText(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Todo esta correcto, único que debes de cambiar es el orden de día, mes y año. Quedando de la siguiente manera.

```
  DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int monthOfYear , int dayOfMonth) {
                eFecha.setText(dayOfMonth+"/"+(dayOfMonth+1)+"/"+year);
            }
        },ano,mes,dia);
        datePickerDialog.show();
```

Answer (score -1):

en esa parte cambia "dia" por "año"

```
}
        ,dia, mes, año);
        datePickerDialog.show();
    }
```

de tal manera que te quedara así

```
 }
        ,año, mes, dia);
        datePickerDialog.show();
    }
```

otro error que encontre fue

```
editfecha.setText(dayOfMonth+"/"+(monthOfYear+1)+"/"+year);
```

cambialo por

```
editfecha.setText(dayOfMonth+"/"+(month+1)+"/"+year);
```

Comment: ¿Y si explicas por qué hacer el cambio?